# I can't connect my email to my email client (VPS - CyberPanel)

Tags: email, vps

i have a server on RackNerd, after I successfully installed Cyberpanel, and my website was online, I created an email on Cyberpanel. Then I connected via my email client (MailBird) but it was always rejected, I have entered the data correctly, such as "Server Hostname", "username" and "password" for my email.. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

By simply saying it was always rejected doesn't provide enough information to debug your issue. Though you could try these:

1. Mail server SSL is issued
2. Postfix & Dovecot is running properly
3. All mail related ports are open in the firewall